# What is tf.nn.max_pool's ksize parameter used for?

Tags: computer-vision, tensorflow

In the definition of `tf.nn.max_pool`, what is `ksize` used for?

```
tf.nn.max_pool(value, ksize, strides, padding, data_format='NHWC', name=None)

Performs the max pooling on the input.

Args:

value: A 4-D Tensor with shape [batch, height, width, channels] and type    tf.float32.
ksize: A list of ints that has length >= 4. The size of the window for each dimension of the input tensor.
```

For instance, if an `input value` is of `tensor :  [1, 64, 64, 3]` and `ksize=3`.what does that mean?

Comment: It takes the maximum over an area of size ksize (kernel size).

Comment: According to the description, ksize captures the size of the window for each dimension of the input tensor. If batch size = 6, ksize=3, does that mean the maxmum will be taken over 3 batches for a given pooling kernel?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/max_pool) states:

> ksize: A list of ints that has length >= 4. The size of the window for each dimension of the input tensor.

In general for images, your input is of shape `[batch_size, 64, 64, 3]` for an RGB image of 64x64 pixels.

The kernel size `ksize` will typically be `[1, 2, 2, 1]` if you have a 2x2 window over which you take the maximum. On the batch size dimension and the channels dimension, `ksize` is `1` because we don't want to take the maximum over multiple examples, or over multiples channels.